# Find consecutive null values started date on date column and bit datatype column

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

```
create table history(response_date date, r_value bit);

insert into values('2023-03-18',1),('2023-03-19',NULL),
('2023-03-20',NULL),('2023-03-21',1),('2023-03-22',NULL),
('2023-03-23',0),('2023-03-24',0),('2023-03-25',NULL),
('2023-03-26',NULL),('2023-03-27',NULL),('2023-03-28',NULL);
```

I need only the starting record date of consecutive null values till the date from the table.

Expected result record date is:

```
2023-03-25
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And have a go, and then let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: What would be the result if also 2023-03-21 had NULL?

Comment: we need find out the starting position of the continuous NULL records till the current date.
for example: in the 10 records, for 6th onwards we have continuous nulls , 
 till last records . we need to find that 6th row id or date, no need consider  when 1 or more rows might be nulls and very next had not null.

Comment: @SNagendra; I have posted a solution and it shall work for any such multiple ranges too as I tested;
Can you verify it

Answer (score 0):

Find consecutive null values started date on date column:

You can do it using  [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) OVER PARTITION BY `r_value` [as in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NiBPSfgO).

```
SELECT MIN(response_date) AS start_date
FROM (
  SELECT response_date, r_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY response_date) AS row_num,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r_value ORDER BY response_date) AS group_num
  FROM history
) t
WHERE r_value IS NULL
GROUP BY (row_num - group_num)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Output :

| start_date |
| --- |
| 2022-03-25 |

Comment: what else if the records have more than 2 nulls values before the consecutive nulls,

Comment: The same query shall written you the `start_date` = 
`2022-03-22` as in this demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/tjOCWsK1

Comment: we need find out the starting position of the continuous NULL records till the current date. for example: in the 10 records, for 6th onwards we have continuous nulls , till last records . we need to find that 6th row id or date, no need consider when 1 or more rows might be nulls and very next had not null.
just i have given a demo , i need query to work as dynamic , please understand above explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (  
    SELECT 
        response_date, 
        r_value, 
        LEAD(r_value) OVER (ORDER BY response_date) AS lead,
        LAG(r_value) OVER (ORDER BY response_date) AS lag
    FROM history
) 
select * 
from cte
where r_value is null
and lead is null
and lag is not null;
```